# Solve it using Ramanujan's Master Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's a problem:

> $$\large \displaystyle\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ { e }^{ -{ x }^{ 3 } }\sin { { x }^{ 3 } } \, dx } $$

This can be easily solved using complex analysis. But how to solve it using Ramanujan's Master theorem? Please help.

Comment: What are $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I've edited it thanks :)

Comment: "This can easily be solved using complex analysis."  You mean replacing the sine by the imaginary part of an exponential and then using real methods?

Comment: yes @RonGordon.

Comment: Yeah, that's not exactly "complex analysis."  But thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RonGordon my friend did it using contour integration.

Comment: Now that I'd like to see.

Comment: I'll have to ask him for that. But the main point here is solving it using RMT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just let $x=u^{1/3}$ and get

$$\frac13 \operatorname{Im}{\int_0^{\infty} du \, u^{-2/3} e^{-(1-i) u}}$$

Since

$$e^{-(1-i) u} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-i)^k}{k!} (-u)^k$$

Then the integral is equal to, by the Master Theorem,

$$\frac13 \Gamma \left ( \frac13 \right )\operatorname{Im} {\left [(1-i)^{-1/3}\right ]} = \Gamma \left ( \frac43 \right ) 2^{-1/6} \sin{\frac{\pi}{12}} $$

because $s=1/3$ and $\phi(k) = (1-i)^k$.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for posting.